# Nservicebus communication between transports

Tags: sql-server, msmq, nservicebus

I’m trying to move one of our endpoints to use **SqlTransport** but there are some legacy endpoints that needs to remain using **MSMQ** for now.

It’s there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the "SqlBridge" sample located here and the readme explains how to do this.
https://github.com/particular/nservicebus.sqlserver.samples